# Zlib and utf-8 in ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, zlib

I'm trying to use zlib to compress out some lengthy strings, some of which may contain unicode characters. At the moment, I'm doing this in ruby, but I think this would apply across any language really. Here's the super basic implementation:

```
require 'zlib'

example = "“hello world”" # note the unicode quotes
compressed = Zlib.deflate(example)
puts Zlib.inflate(compressed)
```

The issue here is that the text comes out as this:

```
\xE2\x80\x9Chello world\xE2\x80\x9
```

...no unicode quotes, just weird unrecognizable characters. Does anyone know of a way that Zlib can be used while retaining unicode characters? Bonus points for an answer in ruby : )

Comment: Which ruby version do you use? I have tested with `ruby-2.0.1/zliby0.0.5` and everything is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems Zlib produces `ASCII-8BIT` as the default encoding upon inflating. To fix it just force the original encoding:

```
require 'zlib'

input = "“hello world”" 
compressed = Zlib.deflate(input)
output = Zlib.inflate(compressed).force_encoding(input.encoding)
```

Or set the encoding manually:

```
output = Zlib.inflate(compressed).force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: you are a gentleman and a scholar. this works perfectly. thanks so much!